# Replace string between brackets with variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'd like to replace character (with variable) inside a string, here is my example:

```
var oldId = 5;
var newId = 6; 
var content = 'text tes_5 as name[5] end';
content = content.replace(new RegExp('name\['+oldId+'\]', 'g'), 'name['+newId+']');
```

Why result is `text tes_5 as name[5] end`?

Comment: Very likely: your regex does not match anything and nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using regex constructor, double escape:

```js
var oldId = 5;
var newId = 6; 
var content = 'text tes_5 as name[5] end';
content = content.replace(new RegExp('name\\['+oldId+'\\]', 'g'), 'name['+newId+']');
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash, because backslash is an escape character for both string literals and regular expressions.

```js
var oldId = 5;
var newId = 6; 
var content = 'text tes_5 as name[5] end';
content = content.replace(new RegExp('name\\['+oldId+'\\]', 'g'), 'name['+newId+']');
console.log(content);
```

In ES6 you can use a template literal with the `String.raw` tag. That prevents it from processing escape sequences inside the literal.

```js
var oldId = 5;
var newId = 6; 
var content = 'text tes_5 as name[5] end';
content = content.replace(new RegExp(String.raw`name\[${oldId}\]`, 'g'), 'name['+newId+']');
console.log(content);
```